# how to use instance class in select body of linq

Tags: c#-4.0, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

```
    Customer cus=new customer();

from c in doc.Descendants(XName.Get("details", name))
                     select 
{
    cus.firstname =c.Element(XName.Get("to", name)).value;
}
```

how to use instance variable in  select body of linq

HI,

I need to access cust instance variable name inside the select statement.

I don't want to create new instance like

```
select new customer
    {
        cus.firstname.
    }
```

Any help in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be much easier with method-based approach:

```
cus.firstname = doc.Descendants(XName.Get("details", name))
                   .Element(XName.Get("to", name))
                   .Value;
```

To fill more properties you can save you `<details>` element into a variable and use it later:

```
var details = doc.Descendants(XName.Get("details", name)).FirstOrDefault();

if(details != null)
{
    cus.firstname = details.Element(XName.Get("to", name)).Value;
    cus.lastname= details.Element(XName.Get("from", name)).Value;
}
```

This will prevent iterating through XML over and over again.

Comment: Thx marc.with this I have to navigate for each property.Is there a way that I cna use object inside select like cus.firstname,cus.lastname